# How to cache results of of get_available_post_statuses() function as it is causing a slow query on a website with over 1 million posts?

Tags: functions, query, optimization, core-modifications

The function `get_available_post_statuses()` is being called by `WP_Posts_List_Table->prepare_items()`, which is calculating posts on each load of admin.

Since this is a core wordpress function and I do not want to modify wordpress core files is there any way to speed up this function? I do not need individual post counts against all statuses as seen below:

[image]